# WebCrawler click on a link not working when minimized

Tags: c#, web-crawler

I have a crawler for this link:
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=Breast%20cancer%5BTitle%2FAbstract%5D
Unfortunately the links are handled by javascripts and there is no Href.
for this purpose I've created a crawler with a Web Browser component. I used this code to click on the link:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.Page").Parent.Children[3].Focus();
            SendKeys.Send("{enter}");
```

but the problem is when I minimize the application, It can not click on the link because it can not focus. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this with JS:

```
var id = "EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.Page"
var script = "document.getElementById('{0}').parentNode.children[3].click()"
script = string.Format(script, id);

webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object [] { script })
```

Additionally, I would advice to embed `jQuery` for better `DOM` navigation.